# How to use WCF service hosted on IIS in an AWS lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, wcf, iis, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have this scenario in which a service hosted on IIS must be used by my AWS lambda function. When I try adding it as a service reference, I'm getting "An error occurred while attempting to discover services in the solution: No services found in the solution.. " error. I don't find any issue with the service, and it is working fine.

Is there any link that I'm missing to make my service available to be used by AWS?

Comment: An error occurred while attempting to find services at '......../Service.svc?wsdl'. The service at the following URI does not have any valid endpoints:'http://............./Launch/Service.svc?wsdl'. ........................ FYI, Im getting this message when I try to discover the service methods

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node.js for Lambda then please do like below,

```js
var soap = require('soap');

var url = 'YouServiceURL.svc?wsdl';

var soapOptions = {
    forceSoap12Headers: true
};

var soapHeader = {
    'wsa:Action': 'http://tempuri.org/MyBinding/MyOperation', 
    'wsa:To': 'YouServiceURL.svc'
};

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var params = {
        param1: event.param1,
        param2: event.param2
    };

    soap.createClient(url, soapOptions, function(err, client) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader, '', 'wsa', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing');
        client.MyOperation(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) callback(err);
            callback(null, data);
        });
    });
}
```

Please find sample code [here](https://gist.github.com/zretscen/798c1c58d69c55e60cb5b9bb96e87f3d)